# xgboost how to know params of the trained models

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

How to retrieve XGBoost  params (i.e. booster object)? XGBoost  version - 0.90 (XGB wrapper)

After this:

```
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_boost_round = best_iteration)
```

This:

```
bst.get_xgb_params()
```

gives the error:

```
'Booster' object has no attribute 'xgb_params'
```

This:

```
config = json.loads(bst.save_config())
print(config)
```

gives the error (it is avaliable from 1.0 version):

```
'Booster' object has no attribute 'save_config'
```

This:

```
bst.attributes()
```

Returns nothing:

```
{}
```

This:

```
bst.attr('Parameters'))
```

Returned:

```
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not trivial to get the booster parameters when using the low-level xgb api.

Here's how I found the booster parameters I was looking for:

```py
# this retrieves all booster and non-booster parameters
import json

config = json.loads(lowlevel_xgb.save_config()) # your xgb booster object
stack = [config]
internal = {}
while stack:
    obj = stack.pop()
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if k.endswith('_param'):
            for p_k, p_v in v.items():
                internal[p_k] = p_v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            stack.append(v)

# retrieve all parameter values from xgb.train in param search dict
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup

lowlevelconfig = {}
for key in search_params_dict: #dict of parameters you want to search for
    lowlevelconfig[key] = nested_lookup(key,config)
```

In my case, I wanted to compare the default low-level api parameters (i.e. using `xgb.train`) to the default parameters using the scikit-wrapper (i.e. using `XGBClassifier`). Unfortunately they are not the same!

If you have the same situation, you can do as I did:

```py
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup
lowlevelconfig = {}
for key in sci_xgb.get_params():#where sci_xgb is your scikit xgb model 
    lowlevelconfig[key] = nested_lookup(key,config)
```

That way, you can compare the booster parameters for both the lowlevel xgb api and the scikit wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way in [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster) to get the parameters for a booster. The [sci-kit learn wrapper](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor) however has the parameters you are looking for like `get_xgb_params()`.

Comment: N. Kiefer, thank you. Tried to use: print(bst.attr('Parameters')). It returned None. I'm sure, it is alive model, because bst.predict(dtest) gives me predictions.